# UWP - MediaPlayerElement vs MediaElement

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

[MediaPlayerElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.MediaPlayerElement) is replacement for "old" [MediaElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.MediaElement).
My question is **Why**?

What is the difference between `MediaPlayerElement` and `MediaElement` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Media Player element** uses Media Playback Source in form of **MediaSource** class which has many methods so it can provide media source by several ways like

1. Streams
2. StorageFiles
3. Uri

and some more as well.
It can also be rendered on any XAML surface like a grid or a button. these are main upgrades in Media Player element but you can read in detail about all features [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/media-playback) .

Answer (score 2):

`MediaPlayerElement` is the evolution of `MediaElement`.

> [In Windows 10, build 1607 and on we recommend that you use `MediaPlayerElement` in place of `MediaElement`. `MediaPlayerElement` has the same functionality as `MediaElement`, while also enabling more advanced media playback scenarios. Additionally, all future improvements in media playback will happen in `MediaPlayerElement`.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement#remarks)

Newer `MediaPlayerElement` decomposes the control in `MediaPlayer` class and a lightweight control over it. This provides better flexibility and new features for playback.

[Another paragraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement#remarks) on the relation of the controls and suggested migration path:

> … For more information about the `MediaPlayer` class, including guidelines on how to transition from `MediaElement` to `MediaPlayerElement`, see the [Media playback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-playback) page.